# RegEx - Match all instances of a single character before a word

Tags: regex

I want to be able to return a single character () before a set of words ("asc or desc") in a text.
For e.g.
Text: col1:asc,col2:desc

Expect it to return ":" twice.
Any ideas how I can grab the preceding character before a word ?

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using? What have you tried so far? Let's see some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var test = [
    'Text: col1:asc,col2:desc',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/.(?=asc|desc)/g);
}));
```

Where

- `.` matches 1 any character
- `(?=asc|desc)` is a positive lookahead, a zero-length assertion that makes sure we have "asc" or "desc" after.
- `/g` is the global flag, search all occurrences

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a regex flavour that supports lookaheads you can do this:

`/\W(?=asc|desc)/`

Demo here: https://regexr.com/3v1sj

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got your intention right, but have you tried

```
(.)\w+
```

Accesing the first group always returns the charakter in front of a word (using js and python)

Comment: This would also return the `,` that separates `col1:asc` and `col2:desc` as `col2` matches `\w+`

Comment: thats why i was not sure about his intentions, either the `,` was just meant as a seperator for his example and not important, but to be precise, its that what he meant, a character before a set of words. Elsewise you couse just modify it to `(.[,]^)\w`  (not tested)